# API between two separate instances of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to figure out a problem I have. I have 2 laravel setups on the same server, each are independent sites controlled via vhosts.

SiteA needs to act as an API to SiteB.  So within SiteA I set up an API by doing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
    Route::post('postProject', array('as' => 'postProject', 'uses' => 'APIController@postProject'));
});
```

For now, the controller function is simply this

```
public function postProject(Project $project)
{
    dd($project);
}
```

So within SiteB I want to call this API. As such, I set up a route which contains the project object (I have tried both get and post)

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/postProject', array('as' => 'projects.postProject', 'uses' => 'APIController@postProject'));
```

And this controller function does the following

```
public function postProject($project)
{
    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $req = $client->request('POST', 'http://localhost/api/v1/postProject', [
        'body' => $project,
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
            'Content-Length' => strlen($project),
        ]
    ]);

    $output = $req->getBody()->getContents();

    return $output;
}
```

I have localhost as an example url so the real url wasnt exposed. The error siteB receives when making the post request is a 404 not found. If on siteA I set up a simple get function that returns something, siteB can execute this API call without any problem. The problem comes about when I am trying to post something from siteB to siteA.

Additionally, when I pass the $project object, is there any way to send over its related models as well? A $project has one to many relationships with a few other models, and ideally I would like to get the related data over.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to eager load the relationships

```
public function postProject()
{
    //dd($project);
    Project::with('relation1', 'relation2')->find($id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly for getting one part of the data.  As relation1 is a many relationship, how would I get back more than one result for this?  Additionally, if relation1 has further child models, is there any way to get these?  Thanks

Comment: first accept the answer
and yes you can chain child relations like
Project::with('relation1.child', 'relation2.child1.child')->find($id);